# OBIEE-How to display last 4 Sunday's data from the selected date

Tags: sql, obiee, bi-publisher

I have a requirement to create an analysis to display sales data for a specific selected date. In the same analysis i have to display last 4 Sunday's data from the selected date.

I have tried AGO function  but it is returning 8 days back data, but i need only last Sundays data. I cannot use filter section as it effects all the columns in analysis.

Comment: No luck. Same people in here as in the official forums.

Comment: Can you be more specific on what you have tried, and the code you used at what places? Thanks.